# Location of add_action relative to callback function

Tags: wordpress

When using `add_action`, is it better to write:

```
add_action('blah', 'my_function');
function my_function() { return $something; }
```

or

```
function my_function() { return $something; }
add_action('blah', 'my_function');
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely a stylistic choice, both behave in exactly the same way.

Personally I prefer

```
add_action('blah', 'my_function');
function my_function() { return $something; }
```

as I feel it's easier to identify the hooks when reading through code. If the function is particularly long then it may not be immediately apparent that it's being hooked in.

For reference, the same question has been asked on quora - http://www.quora.com/WordPress/In-WordPress-is-it-best-practice-to-add_action-before-or-after-your-custom-function

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. Mostly people follow.

```
function my_function() { return $something; }
add_action('blah', 'my_function');
```

I use

```
add_action('blah', 'my_function');
function my_function() { return $something; }
```

I feel it's easier to read code this way. But there is no strict rule here.